# How to manage a vector of struct type XPoint?

Tags: c++, vector, struct

good evening.
Yeah I'm a newbie in this world of C and C++.
What should I do to solve this:

```
int i;
vector <XPoint> originales;
originales.reserve(7);
XPoint asteroid[5];
for(k = 0; k < 7; k++){
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        asteroid[i].x = rand() % 20 - 100;
        asteroid[i].y = rand() % 20 - 100;
    }
    originales.push_back(*asteroid);
}//end of first for

/*
    The XPoint structure contains:
    typedef struct {
        short x, y; 
    } XPoint; 
*/
```

When I print the coordinates are incomplete. Is this means that You can't save XPoint[] arrays inside a vector of XPoint?. In that case, how can I fix it?
Please help!

Comment: You seem to be filling an array of 5 items in order to put only **one** of those items into your vector. Do you need that 5 item array?

Comment: To Galik: Yeah, I made a mistake. I need the five pairs of coordinates, not only the first one.                                                                                      Barry: thank you. I didn´t know the relation between 'vector' and arrays '[]' I'll see what I can do

Answer (score 1):

Arrays and vectors are not compatible. The only thing you can `push_back` onto `originales` is an `XPoint`. But `vector`s already handle this sort of thing very well - they were made for it! - so you don't need the extra array at all:

```
for(k = 0; k < 7; k++){
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        XPoint asteroid;
        asteroid.x = rand() % 20 - 100;
        asteroid.y = rand() % 20 - 100;
        originales.push_back(asteroid);
    }
}
```